# Excel UDF to copy cell content to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to implement an UDF that takes a cell reference as range and copies content of the cell to a new worksheet. However, when I call the UDF in excel, it throws a #value error. I am new to VBA.

I have written the following code:

```
Function CopyCellToNewWorksheet(rng As Range) As String
    ' Declare variables
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim copyValue As String
    
    ' Set variables
    copyValue = rng.Value
    
    ' Create new worksheet and copy value
    Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
    newSheet.Name = "New Worksheet"
    newSheet.Range("A1").Value = copyValue
    
    ' Return new worksheet name
    CopyCellToNewWorksheet = newSheet.Name
End Function
```

Comment: A UDF in a cell can't do that. There are workarounds but this is, frankly, a bad idea.

Comment: Very much agree with @Rory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel4-excel12 gives some background on how functions & macros are classified. When you try and write to a cell, the `xlSet` function is called internally, and that is blocked on UDFs called from the s/sheet. This is deliberate; if this was allowed the whole calculation tree would be broken as Excel would no longer know the dependencies between cells. There are workarounds, but going out of your way to deliberately circumvent Excel's valid restrictions is a recipe for corrupted s/sheets.

Comment: Maybe instead consider using an Event trigger - perhaps when the contents of a specific cell are changed the routine runs. Or alternatively, place a button/shape on the worksheet that will cause the routine to run based on the value of a specific cell?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the prompt response. As I had mentioned, I am a newbie. I am trying to perform monte-carlo simulation using excel. Trying to figure out what is the best way to copy the output cell content for all iterations to a new worksheet. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why not use an input box

```
Sub CopyValuesToNewSheet()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range to copy", "Copy Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No range selected. Operation cancelled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = "Copied Values"
    
    rng.Copy
    newSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    MsgBox "Values copied successfully to new sheet: " & newSheet.Name
    
End Sub
```